# Modify a substring without altering the string in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I have this string:

```
14-Nov-2018 10:14:44.775 client IP1#59098: view internal: query: DOMAIN IN A + (IP2)
```

I want to parse it to delete minutes and seconds from the hour. The result would be the next:

```
14-Nov-2018 10 client IP1#59098: view internal: query: DOMAIN IN A + (IP2)
```

I get this string from a file, so It would be perfect if It is achieved with a pipe. My current line is as follows:

```
cat $dns_logs | grep "$date" | HERE WOULD BE YOUR SOLUTION > $temp_queries
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/(:[0-9]{2}){2}\.[0-9]{3} //'
```

Comment: Thanks! I modify your solution and It works: sed -r 's/:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3} / /g'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with `awk` then could you please try following.

```
echo "14-Nov-2018 10:14:44.775 client IP1#59098: view internal: query: DOMAIN IN A + (IP2)" | 
awk '
  match($0,/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1),substr(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),1,2),substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
  next
}
1'
```

Comment: Wow thanks! That is interesting since I didn't know how to match inside AWK. Thanks again!

Comment: @Miguel.G, your welcome, you could try to encourage people by up-voting their helpful answers too on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The whole line can be done as

```
awk -v d="$date" '($0 ~ d){$2=substr($2,1,2); print}' "$dns_logs"
```